# Datatable warning: Requested unknown parameter 'id' for row 276

Tags: javascript, jquery, spring-mvc, datatables

I have in total 276 rows in my datatable, where I could able to retrieve these from my datatbase using JQuery 1.11.3. when I was adding new row to that datatable, it is throwing this warning message:

> Datatables warning: table id=featuresList- Requested unknown parameter 'id' for row 276.

"id" is the name of my database column. When I open the requested link in other tab it was returning me this row id. I am using jQuery 1.11.3. I'm able to insert this data into database but can't able to add this new row to datatable.

**Javascript**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#featuresList').dataTable({
      "bProcessing": true,
      "bServerSide": false,
      "sort": "position",
      "bStateSave": false,
      "iDisplayLength": 10,
      "iDisplayStart": 0,
      "fnDrawCallback": function() {
        //Get page numer on client. Please note: number start from 0 So
        //for the first page you will see 0 second page 1 third page 2...
        //Un-comment below alert to see page number
        //alert("Current page number: "+this.fnPagingInfo().iPage);    
      },
      "sAjaxSource": "/maintainFeatures/maintainFeaturesData",
      aoColumns: [
        {
          "mData": "id",
          "bVisible": false
        }, 
        {
          "mData": "dataId"
        }, 
        {
          "mData": "description"
        },
        {
          "mData": null,
          "bSearchable": false,
          "bSortable": false,
          "mRender": function(data, type, full) {
            var id1 = full.id;
            return "<a class='table-action-deletelink' href='javascript:alert(" + id1 + ");'>Edit</a>";

          }
        }, 
        {
          "mData": null,
          //"sName": "Id",      
          "bSearchable": false,
          "bSortable": false,
          "mRender": function(data, type, full) {
            //console.dir( oObj.aData[0] ) ;
            var id1 = full.id;
            return "<a class='table-action-deletelink' href='/maintainFeatures/delete?id=" + full.id + "'>Delete</a>";


          }
        }
      ]
  })
  .makeEditable({
      sUpdateURL: "/maintainFeatures/update",
      sAddURL: "/maintainFeatures/AddData",
      sAddHttpMethod: "GET", //Used only on google.code live example because google.code server do not support POST request
      sDeleteURL: "/maintainFeatures/delete",
      sDeleteHttpMethod: "GET", //Used only on google.code live example because google.code server do not support POST request
      "aoColumns": [
        {
          cssclass: "required"
        },
        null, //null for read-only columns
        {
          indicator: 'Saving...',
          tooltip: 'Click to select town',
          loadtext: 'loading...',
          type: 'select',
          onblur: 'submit',
          data: '{"London":"London","Liverpool":"Liverpool","Portsmouth": "Portsmouth","Edinburgh":"Edinburgh", "Blackburn":"Blackburn","Kent":"Kent","Essex":"Essex","Oxon":"Oxon","Lothian":"Lothian", "West Sussex":"West Sussex","Lanarkshire":"Lanarkshire", "Birmingham":"Birmingham","East Sussex":"East Sussex","Surrey":"Surrey"}'
        }
      ]
  });

});
```

**HTML**

```
<table id="featuresList" class="table table-striped table-bordered" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
        <thead>
            <tr>

                <th>Id</th>
                <th>Data_ID</th>
                <th>Description</th>
                <th>Edit</th>
                <th>Delete</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
    </table>
     <button id="btnAddNewRow" value="Ok">Add new record</button> 


<form id="formAddNewRow" action="#" title="Add new feature">
    <input type="hidden" id="id" name="id" value="-1" rel="0" />
    <label for="name">DataID</label><input type="text" name="dataId" id="dataId" rel="1" />
    <br />
    <label for="name">Description</label><input type="text" name="description" id="description" rel="2"/>
    <br />   

</form>
```

**Java controller class**

```
 @RequestMapping(value="/AddData")
  public @ResponseBody Long add(HttpServletRequest request, Model model) 
  {            
      String dataid  =(request.getParameter("dataId"));
      String desc    =(request.getParameter("description"));
      System.out.println(dataid+";"+desc);

      Feature f= new Feature();
      f.setDataId(dataid);
      f.setDescription(desc);
      f = featureService.create(f);
      return f.getId();        
  }
```

Comment: There is no code for adding a new row, most likely that is where the problem is.

Comment: How do you handle the form submit?

Comment: @Gyrocode.com, I think there is no code is needed to add a new row. whenever  I click on the OK button of new add form, it(JQuery) will hit the SAddURL and get the new row id back. Based on the new row id it receives, it will add that row data dynamically. I am new to JQuery and this is what I have heard. please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: @JamesJithin, Hope my last comment answers your questions too.

Comment: @Rakesh, I still can't believe that! How will it handle in case of more than one form!

Comment: @JamesJithin, I never think of it. Good question, though.  Since, we have only one form requirement.

Comment: @Gyrocode.com, Can you please show me sample code to add a new row?

Comment: See API method [`row.add()`](http://datatables.net/reference/api/row.add%28%29). It is still not clear how you handle your form submit. If page is reloaded after submit, you don't need `row.add()`. It's needed if you use Ajax to submit your form.

Comment: @Gyrocode.com I'm using Ajax to get the data from database to datatable. all requests/responses are performed by ajax calls. Yes, page would be reloaded when I hit AddRowForm submit button. it is also returning the new form id when submitted the data to java controller class but not adding dynamically to the datatable.